# drop down for table headers without jQuery

Tags: html, reactjs

Is a dropdown for a html table header possible without jQuery. Using react javascript and css? I'm not sure how to go about this since you can't have  within your tr and th

Comment: An example of what your are looking for (link to a site or a screenshot) would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Yes it is possible without jQuery, as there were implementations for the said dropdown before jQuery too :P. On a serious note, do post what you have researched and tried first.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean with "you can't have <div> within your tr and th", because you can have divs in th elements. The <div> in your text is invisible, by the way, causing the question to be unclear.